# SQL copy from one table to another with changing ID value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, copy

I have two tables:

## A

```
ID   VALUE
----------
1      7
2      5
3      44
4      982
5      1
6      0
7      671
```

## B

```
ID     VALUE
---------------
1       6
2       6
3       77
4       22
```

How do I copy data from #B to #A to get a different ID (one bigger than the MAX in #A)? For example I need to get

```
ID   VALUE
1      7
2      5
3      44
4      982
5      1
6      0
7      671
8       6
9       6
10      77
11      22
```

Comment: Is the `ID` column in your Table A set to auto-increment?  If it is, then we don't need to worry about the value of `ID` because the SQL engine will take care of it for us.

Answer (score 1):

Either make it an `IDENTITY` column which auto-increments, or this:

```
INSERT INTO A
   SELECT b.ID + (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM A) AS ID, b.Value
   FROM B
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e67e/1/0)

The select is slightly different if the ID in table B has gaps. Then those gaps are transferred.

Comment: Accidentally voted you down, but then couldn't return it to zero.  Consider this a freebee :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the `ID` column in `TableA` is not already set to auto-increment, do the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE TableA MODIFY COLUMN ID INT auto_increment
```

Now you can just insert all the records from `TableB` into `TableA`:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (VALUE)
SELECT VALUE
FROM TableB
```

It is not a great idea to rely on the business logic in your query to maintain the order of the `ID` column.  Instead, let SQL take care of it for you; it was designed for this purpose.

Comment: Please specify which dbms this works for? (No one specified by OP.)

Comment: This would work for MySQL.  If you have another DB running let me know and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Is there any other way beside auto increment? I am using MS Sql 2008 R2

Comment: Yes, use Tim Schmelter's solution (the _other_ Tim).